# offset not selecting distinct values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I debugged my query for some time now. I narrowed the problem down to this:

I've got a local database with 44 movies. Running the query:

```
Movie.order(:name).joins(:movie_images).offset(40).limit(10).uniq
```

I retrieve the last 4 movies as expected.

Now I wanted to order the results by the `movie_images.created_at` field instead of the `movies.name`. I had to add the `select` clause as `distinct` requires that.

```
Movie.select("movies.*, movie_images.created_at").order("movie_images.created_at").joins(:movie_images).offset(40).limit(10).uniq
```

This returns the last 4 movies as expected, but it additionally returns the first 6 movies again (now being duplicates as loaded earlier), adding up to the set `limit` of 10.

My 44 movies each have 2 images, each with a different `created_at` time. So my assumption is that there are 88 distinct results according to the select clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT movies.*, movie_images.created_at
```

Setting the `offset` to 80 returns the last 8 results, proving my point.

But how would you order by `movie_images.created_at` while still only selecting distinct movies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a GROUP BY statement instead, like so:

```
SELECT movies.id, MAX(movie_images.created_at) mi_created_at
  FROM movies JOINS movie_images ON movies.id = movie_images.movie_id
  GROUP BY movies.id
  ORDER BY mi_created_at
```

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385572/better-sql-group-vs-select-distinct) answer on Stackoverflow for the differences of GROUP BY and DISTINCT statements in PostgreSQL.

Another thing to consider would be a different design. Rails offers the `touch` option on a [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) association. Meaning it will update the `updated_at` column of the parent object if the child object changes (i.e. a new movie image is being created, etc).

```
class MovieImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie, touch: true
end
```

With that in place you can simply sort by the `updated_at` column of your `Movie` object.

```
Movie.order(updated_at: :asc).offset(40).limit(10)
```

Of course this would also contain updates like the `Movie` object itself being updated, or a `MovieImage` getting destroyed, etc. If you purely want to consider the creation of a new `MovieImage` object, you could also work with an `after_create` callback, and a specific column on your `Movie` model:

```
class MovieImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie

  after_create :touch_movie
  def touch_movie
    movie.update(last_movie_image_created_at: Time.now)
  end
end
```

And then use that column in your query:

```
Movie.order(:last_movie_image_created_at).offset(40).limit(10)
```

With those small design changes, I think it's also more readable and obvious what one's doing instead of having endless distinct or group by queries.

Comment: thx allot @Vapire, I could use both of your design improvements: `touch: true` makes total sense at the `movie_image`. I could also use `after_create callback` to catch the creation of the first image, which I wanted to sort by :)